# What parameters should I use in my EIP1559 transaction for a fast confirmation time

Tags: gas, gas-limit, eip-1559

Looking to take part in some minting gas wars and looking to prepare a transaction before hand. What values should I use for my **Base Fee Per Gas**, **Max Fee Per Gas**, and **Max Priority Fee Per Gas** to ensure that I can get a high change of my transaction getting confirmed.

Comment: MetaMask has a good [article](https://metamask.io/1559) on EIP-1559.